# unable to view php file without it's extension when hosted a php file on windows dedicated server on IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am unable to view files that are hosted on IIS (windows dedicated server 2016) without file extension ".php"

ex:

Below URL is yielding proper output:
http://example.com/test/test.php

while this version says :
http://example.com/test/test

"Server Error 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

checked & enabled the directory browsing, FastCGI, we can able to access other files such as images, pdf, which are the same link.

went through the link for possible solutions on translating ".htaccess" to "web.config" cleared cache & DNS flushed but still, the problem persists.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: If you have gone through the link for possible solutions on translating ".htaccess" to "web.config", then what were the rules added to IIS configuration? Edit your question to include them, so others can see what's still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are nothing like PHP-extensionless handler in IIS, so IIS will never able to handle PHP without extension by default.

To resolve this issue, you have to use URL rewrite module to rewrite extensionless url to .php url.

For example, you may need to rewrite test\test to test\test.php. So when you input test\test, the server will return test.php's content.

```
<rule name="rewrite">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/test/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:0}.php" />
                </rule>
```

[image]

[image]

Since I'm not sure which URL require to be rewritten. You could modify this rule.

Comment: Thank you.! it worked.
enabled rewrite rule in webconfig has resolved the problem of loading php with it's extension when hosted on IIS windows dedicated server 2016.

ex:    
<rule name="Imported Rule 2">
      <match url="^(.*?)/?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php" />
</rule>
 <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.+)\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="/{R:1}" /></rule>

Answer (score -2):

Make a .htaccess file in main folder and use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file_name?$ file_name.php
```

Comment: IIS does not support .htaccess files.